# SQL add up numbers to the same country

Tags: mysql, sql

My friend and I are making a mockup database of a movie rental.
We are having trouble with a select command.

> A list of all movies, showing how often (number) a movie was rented per nationality of customers. Sorted by frequency (largest first).

We tried by grouping the count(id) however it shows up as single rows

```
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+
| name                                          | Country     | Rental    |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+
| Star Wars                                     | USA         |         1 |
| Star Wars                                     | France      |         1 |
| Star Wars                                     | India       |         1 |
| Star Wars                                     | Italy       |         1 |
| Star Wars                                     | USA         |         1 |
```

but we want something like this

```
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+
| name                                          | Country     | Rental    |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+
| Star Wars                                     | USA         |         2 |
| Star Wars                                     | France      |         1 |
| Star Wars                                     | India       |         1 |
| Star Wars                                     | Italy       |         1 |
```

the Select command looks like this right now

```
select Film.name as Film, Nationality.country as Country, count(ausleihen.ausleih_id) as Ausleihen
from
    Nationality
    join Client on Nationality.nationality_id = Client.nationality_id
    join rental on Client.client_id = rental.client_id
    join Film on rental.film_id = Film.film_id
    group by  rental.rental_id 
    order by  film.name;
```

our tables look like this:

```
create table rental(
  rental_id serial,
  film_id bigint unsigned not null,
  client_id bigint unsigned not null,
  rental_price float(25) not null,
  rental_date date,
  return_date date,

  primary key(ausleih_id),
    foreign key(film_id) references Film(film_id) on update cascade on delete restrict,
  foreign key(client_id) references Client(client_id) on update cascade on delete restrict
);

  create table Film(
    film_id serial,
    category_id bigint unsigned not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    film_price float(25) not null,
  

    primary key(film_id),
    foreign key (category_id) references Category(category_id) on update cascade on delete cascade
  );

  create table Nationality(
    nationality_id serial,
    country varchar(255) not null,

    primary key(nationality_id)
  );
```

Comment: Change your group by to `group by Film.name, Nationality.country`

Comment: ausleihen is not in join critera.  is this a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate by the correct columns:

```
select f.name as Film, n.country as Country, count(*) as Ausleihen
from Nationality n join
     Client c
     on n.nationality_id = c.nationality_id join
     rental r
     on c.client_id = r.client_id join
     Film f 
     on r.film_id = f.film_id
group by f.name as Film, n.country
order by f.name;
```

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.